# PHP SOAP Request not right

Tags: php, soap, xmlhttprequest, soap-client

i try to build following SOAP Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckSomething xmlns="http://service.mydomain.com/">
      <User>
        <username>user123</username>
        <password>geheim</password>
      </User>
      <ItemXY>something</ItemXY>
    </CheckSomething>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://service.mydomain.com/Services.asmx?wsdl",array( "trace" => 1 ));
$Param = array (
  'username' => "user123",
  'password' => "geheim"
);
$info = $soapClient->__call("CheckSomething", array("User" => $Param,"ItemXY" => "something"));
echo "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($soapClient->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://service.mydomain.com/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:CheckSomething/>
<param1>something</param1>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the wsdl section for this Service:

```
<s:element name="CheckSomething">
  <s:complexType>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="User" type="tns:Validation"/>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ItemXY" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Can anybody help me to form the right SOAP request?

How to remove the `ns1` in the result Tag an give the correct Array User and ItemXY?

Comment: looks like you nedd to modify your wsdl file

Comment: i can't access the wsdl file, this file comes from a customer

Comment: so your request doesn't execute? soap client sould work fine with SoapClient and predefined WSDL file.

Comment: I want to create a request like the first in my Thread, but i get a wrong request from SOAP CLient. There is no User Section and the param1 is not the right named Tag.

Comment: I think you shouldn't care about how is your request looks like. Web servicesare created for not to care about this.

Comment: The Problem is that the leave is wrong so the service cant process the request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After i modify the PHP Code to:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("http://service.mydomain.com/Services.asmx?wsdl",array( "trace" => 1 ));
$user_param = array (
  'username' => "user123",
  'password' => "geheim"
);
$service_param = array (
  'User' => $user_param,
  "ItemXY" => "something"
);

$info = $soapClient->__call("CheckSomething", array($service_param));
echo "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($soapClient->__getLastRequest()) ."\n";
```

it works!

Comment: thanks for this response. for readers: sometimes just wrap your array of arguments into array is enough.