# How to read soapenv:Envelope xml node in php?

Tags: php, xml

I have below given xml data file. i want to read  node. can anyone help me out.

```
$this->soapResponse
```

has response xml data.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<addItemToShoppingCartResponse xmlns="http://www.sample.com/services">
<ack>Warning</ack>
</addItemToShoppingCartResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

i am trying

```
$xml = new  SimpleXMLElement($this->soapResponse);
print_r((string)$xml->addItemToShoppingCartResponse->ack );
```

Comment: Take a look at this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770898/soapenvelope-soap-envenvelope-php

Comment: I want to read this xml file. i have got this in response.
this is not request xml.

Comment: To whoever closed this: This question is about **how to adress data items in a soap response** - and not about requesting stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `simplexml_load_string()`, then register your namespaces with `registerXPathNamespace()` and then you can start to adress your items by using `xpath()`.
Then you are able to use these namespaces to adress the items correctly in your xpath query.

```
<?php

$xml = '
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<addItemToShoppingCartResponse xmlns="http://www.sample.com/services">
    <ack>Warning</ack>
</addItemToShoppingCartResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml, NULL, NULL, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

// register your used namespace prefixes
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap-env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('services', 'http://www.sample.com/services'); // ? ns not in use

// then use xpath to adress the item you want (using this NS)
$nodes = $xml->xpath('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/services:addItemToShoppingCartResponse/services:ack');
$ack = (string) $nodes[0];
var_dump($ack);
```

---

**Question** from comments:

"What if i file have subnodes in addItemToShoppingCartResponse node? How to apply foreach loop?"

**Answer**

Use xpath to travel and select the node, which is one level above your items. Here it's "ship". You will get all the items underneath ship. Then might use an foreach iteration to get the content.

Note: Nodes are always "lists/arrays" - so you need the `[0]`. But you see that, when using `var_dump()`, too.

```
// example data looks like this
// addItemToShoppingCartResponse -> ship -> item
$xml = '
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<addItemToShoppingCartResponse xmlns="http://www.sample.com/services">
   <ack>warrning</ack> 
   <ship>
     <item>231</item>
     <item>232</item>
   </ship>
</addItemToShoppingCartResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
';

// load xml like above + register NS

// select items node (addItemToShoppingCartResponse -> ship)
$items = $xml->xpath('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/services:addItemToShoppingCartResponse/services:ship/services:item');

// iterate item nodes
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
  //var_dump($item);
  echo (string) $item[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
what if i file have subnodes in addItemToShoppingCartResponse node.(i mean how to apply foreach loop)
<addItemToShoppingCartResponse><ack>warrning</ack>
<ship>
<itm>231</item>
<itm>231</item>
</ship>
</addItemToShoppingCartResponse>

Comment: I've add the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SimpleXML, then you will have to use namespaces and the `children` method :

```
echo (string) $xml->children("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
    ->Body
    ->children()
    ->addItemToShoppingCartResponse
    ->ack;
```

Output :

```
Warning
```